# C# object reference from Html to Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

My domain object `Store` holds a reference to the object `Chain`:

```
public class Store
{
    public Chain Chain { get; set; }
}
```

On creating a new store there is the possibility to set the associated chain. I am realising this by passing the chain objects via ViewBag and use the `Html.DropDownListFor` for selection:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.Chain,
    new SelectList(ViewBag.Chains, "Id", "Name"))
```

So far so good, but back in the controller (after submitting) the chain property  is null. I figured that I can set the DropDownList to `Chain.Id` but then I need to load the entity again. Is there a better way to get/keep the correct reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a better way to get/keep the correct reference?

No, that's how HTML works. Only the selected value is sent to the server and you need to use this value to load the corresponding entity. Please learn HTML before getting into ASP.NET MVC development. It would help you very much. That's the correct way:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.Chain.Id,
    new SelectList(ViewBag.Chains, "Id", "Name")
)
```

Well, as a matter of a real fact, to be totally honest with you the most correct way to handle this is to get rid of all `ViewBag` crap and use a real view model in your application:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.ChainId,
    Model.AvailableChains
)
```

where `AvailableChains` will of course be a property of type `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` on the view model you prepared for this view. You should always be using a view model and never be passing your domain models to your view if you want to be doing ASP.NET MVC the *right way*.

And here's how your view model might look like:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int ChainId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AvailableChains { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Hmm that sounds not like a clean programming style to set just the Id of the associated element, load and allocate it again... in the domain object! I think it is time for a ViewModel?!

Comment: cross post with the same thoughts :-) Thanks again, I will heed your advice!